# Rails can't get PDFkit wkhtmltopdf to install on iMac

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdfkit

I'm trying to use PDFkit gem in a Rails app.  But, I can't get wkhtmltopdf loaded.  I first tried this:

```
$ brew install wkhtmltopdf
```

And got this:

```
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/qt-  4.8.0-bottle.tar.gz
########################################################################   100.0%
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: d03b56811d2cac933b6103bd4c8ac636dea3b877
Got: 2bfe00c5112b0d2a680cd01144701f8937846096
Archive: /Users/burtondav/Library/Caches/Homebrew/qt-4.8.0.bottle.tar.gz
(To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.)
```

So, I downloaded wkhtmltopdf.app and put it into my Applications folder.  Then I created pdfkit.rb in the config/initializers folder.  With this code:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|

config.wkhtmltopdf = 'C:\Applications\wkhtmltopdf.app' #Path to your wkhtmltppdf installation directory

config.root_url = "http://localhost" # Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.

end
```

Now, I get the following error:

```
No wkhtmltopdf executable found at C:\Applications\wkhtmltopdf.app
```

Thanks for the help!!

UPDATE

Will PDFkit work on Heroku?

UPDATE2

I ran this in the command line and it worked! So, I know it's on my Mac.

```
 /Applications/wkhtmltopdf.app/Contents/MacOS/wkhtmltopdf "http://www.google.com" google.pdf
```

UPDATE3

I put it into a folder of the same name within Applications and tried this:

```
 config.wkhtmltopdf = '/Applications/wkhtmltopdf ' #Path to your wkhtmltppdf installation directory
```

But, that didn't work either.

Comment: Yes, PDFkit works on heroku.

Comment: How do I configure it in my Rails app to run on Heroku?

Comment: Check this link... http://blog.mattgornick.com/using-pdfkit-on-heroku

Comment: Please add your own answer if you get it working for help other :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the wkhtmltopdf binary to `/Applications/wkhtmltopdf.app/Contents/MacOS/wkhtmltopdf` (or the installation directory to `/Applications/wkhtmltopdf.app/Contents/MacOS` and it'll work.

You can probably also add that to your PATH for convenience.

Comment: 0.12 appears to install with a .pkg and does everything correctly.